# Is it possible to solve the following system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The system is the following:
$$-2x + 4y = 7$$
$$ 3x - 5y = 4$$
i don't usually ask for these kind of things,seems really easy but this really got me. i've tried by many methods; but everytime i check it, it doesn't satisfy one equation.
Once i got $Y=15.5$ and $X = -27.5$. As you can see it satisfies the first equation, but not the second one.
Is it even possible to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ $$-2x + 4y = 7$$
$(2)$ $$ 3x - 5y = 4$$

From $(1)$, we get $$2x= 4y-7 \implies x=\frac{4y-7}{2}$$

Substiting into $(2)$:

$$3\cdot\frac{4y-7}{2} -5y = 4$$

$$\implies 3(4y-7)-10y=8$$

$$\implies 12y-10y = 8+21 \implies2y = 29 \implies y=\frac{29}{2}$$

Then $$x = \frac{4\cdot \frac{29}{2}-7}{2} = \frac{2\cdot 29 -7}{2} = \frac{51}{2} $$

These values of $x$ and $y$ satisfy both equations as you would expect.

Comment: Oh, i see,  i did it by other method but i missed the sum.; $2y = 21 + 8$ and i did $2y=31$.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is described by the augmented matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
-2 & 4 & 7 \\
3 & -5 & 4
\end{array}\right]
$$
Using [elementary row operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Elementary_row_operations), we may find the [reduced row-echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) of the system.

First, scale $\DeclareMathOperator{Row}{Row}\Row_1$ by $-1/2$ to obtain
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -2 & -\frac{7}{2} \\
3 & -5 & 4
\end{array}\right]
$$
Next, add $-3\Row_1$ to $\Row_2$ to get
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -2 & -\frac{7}{2} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{29}{2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Finally, add $2\Row_2$ to $\Row_1$ to obtain
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & 0 & \frac{51}{2} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{29}{2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
This tells us that $x=51/2$ and $y=29/2$.